# How to Insert Fill color in image with fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

What fabric.js function allows to fill colors in the image?

I want to load image with black lines and white background for painting.

I have a input color with different colors for the user add colour to image in the white parts

Another doubt:
How do I automatically resize the image the same size as the canvas?

https://jsfiddle.net/gislef/s3rvoon6/

```
fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;
    fabric.Object.prototype.padding = 5;


  var $ = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};


  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.setHeight(300);
        canvas.setWidth(500);

    fabric.Image.fromURL('http://coloring.thecolor.com/color/images/Fish2.gif', function(oImg) {
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To resize the image to height and width of canvas you can do:

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://coloring.thecolor.com/color/images/Fish2.gif', function(oImg) {
  oImg.scaleToWidth(canvas.getWidth());
  //oImg.scaleToHeight(canvas.getHeight());
  canvas.add(oImg);
});
```

Regarding fill color there is nothing like that as of now.
There is removeWhite filter that can be modified to replace the white with another color, but this would remove all the white instead of a zone of white.

If you are aiming at application that looks like a coloring book for children you should try to use svg assets and color them by shape.
This means that you have to carefully create your own assets before using them with the application.